# Create and use an index inside a transaction

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a slow delete query. As suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138270) when I add an index I get much better results. Beside this scenario I don't need this index, so what I did is:

1. Added the index.
2. Deleted the rows.
3. Dropped the index.

Is it possible to do these 3 steps in one transactions and not having this index committed at all but still be able to use it in the `delete` query?

Comment: Yes you can, you can create an index within a transaction. However, creating the index takes time, the database has to read the entire table and write the result to the index. For the delete without the index, it has to read the entire table as well. I don't think creating an index on the fly would speed up the entire proces.

Comment: You can, but what is the point?  If you rollback the CREATE, you also rollback the DELETE.  If the commit the DELETE, you also commit the CREATE.

Comment: @jjanes: you could use a savepoint to avoid the rollback of the delete. But I still don’t see any benefit of doing so…

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for your comment. I don't know if there is a benefit, but take a look at the linked question. Adding a temporary index on the foreign key gave a major improvement on a delete  query. In my case I stopped the query without the index after 2 hours, and it took less then 20 seconds with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create an index inside a transaction (unless you are using `CONCURRENTLY`). However, that is a bad idea: `CREATE INDEX` locks the table against all data modifications, and that lock will be held until your transaction ends. So you will affect concurrent SQL statements way more that you would with an extra index in place.

Comment: @JakeBiesinger I see. That is completely unrelated to this question. You may want to open a new one.

Comment: It seemed like the OP and I might have been in a similar situation -- a one-time data migration where a throw-away index could help speed things up (FK speedup mentioned above) or, in my case, affect other semantics like serialization retries. Anywho, I've now asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996777/how-should-i-approach-updating-a-hot-table

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing yourself any favors by creating the index, running the query, then dropping the index.

The computational and I/O workload for CREATE INDEX is nontrivial. And, the overhead for maintaining an index is modest unless you have an extremely large number of changes made to your table in production (INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs) between runs of your delete query. And the storage overhead is very likely quite reasonable. HDD / SSD storage is cheap and getting cheaper. Having the index in place won't hurt SELECT query performance, and might help some queries.

So while you *can* create the index, run the query, and drop the index inside a transaction, you're almost certainly better off creating the index and leaving it in place.